# Python install datatable in anaconda failed

Tags: python, datatable, anaconda, conda, channel

I'm trying to install datatable package through Anaconda with the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge datatable
```

It gave me error

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - datatable

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I search datatable in anaconda.org, but seem like the channel that contain datatable is conda-forge.

So I blindly add some random channel to see if it work:

```
conda config --add channels keras
conda config --add channels pickle
conda config --add channels nltk
```

Now I can't even access to conda-forge

```
conda install -c conda-forge datatable

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for channel keras <https://conda.anaconda.org/keras>

The channel is not accessible or is invalid.

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

```
conda config --show channels
channels:
  - nltk
  - pickle
  - keras
  - defaults
```

Comment: are you set on conda-forge? ```pip install datable``` could otherwise be an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package entries on Anaconda Cloud list what platforms for which a particular package is available, and `datatable` currently only has **osx-64** and **linux-64**. If you would like the Conda Forge feedstock to build **win-64** versions (OP's platform), then [file an Issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/datatable-feedstock/issues) requesting this, or add it to the recipe with [a PR](https://github.com/conda-forge/datatable-feedstock/pulls).

Otherwise, please do not randomly add channels to your configuration. Packages are not necessarily compatible across channels, so one needs to be very specific with what channels are added to configuration. Also, Anaconda Cloud lets anyone create channels, so you should be much more cautious about what channels are trustworthy. OP seems to be randomly adding channels based on common Python package names - that's not a thing! I recommend cleaning up your `.condarc` to remove those channels.

Comment: Thanks. It's sad I have to quit Python datatable, don't like pandas... Got to do data cleaning with R.

Comment: I feel that "currently only has" should be "now only has" because I'm looking at my Spyder 4.2.5 / Python 3.8.8 setup in Win10 from a couple of years or so ago and it has datatable 0.11.1 installed and working just peachy. Is it the case as it seems that it used to be supported and for some reason has been dropped, or might I have installed it through some other route as I honestly can't remember, and it would be nice to get it working on a new setup with Windows 11 with 3.10

Comment: @Nick still no Conda package for it (https://anaconda.org/search?q=datatable) and [looking at PRs](https://github.com/conda-forge/datatable-feedstock/pulls) seems like no one is actively maintaining the Conda Forge version. Maybe you installed it from PyPI?